# How do I organize my project files in Visual Studio in a Setup Project?

Tags: file-management, visual-studio-2010

I have a set of schemas that I use in a C# program.  I've created a Visual Studio Installer "Setup" Project.  Whenever I add those files into the project using the project's "File System" I get a massive list of files in the Solution Explorer:

[image]

Is there a way to organize these files into a folder?  Right clicking doesn't produce the typical "Add" -> "Folder" that typical VS projects have.

Comment: What about right clicking, and then add new solution folder?

Comment: @soandos that doesn't work, as this is a specific to the project.  Similar to dependencies or references.

Comment: I have never seen anything other than a long list. Although I've not tested it in VS2012, in 2005 and 2010 I think we're stuck with a potentially long and messy list!

Comment: @dave they no longer have installer setup projects in VS 2012.

Comment: i think you will get answers for this on stackoverflow

Comment: @tgkprog it's not really programming related though.  I don't think it's a good fit for SO.

Comment: well seeing that you did not get answers here, i suggest you try there, as more eyes see questions there. i for one will upvote it as its close to the process of programming and stack is full of deployment questions. if u do post it there leave a comment for me here with URL so i can find it easily.